API to get historical SOL/USDT price?
Is there an API to get get SOL ticker price w.r.t. USDT for a particular timestamp? I want to use it to account for taxes
I tried using the Binance API as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66397480/811335 but that returns error probably because of the location?
"Service unavailable from a restricted location according to 'b. Eligibility' in https://www.binance.com/en/terms. Please contact customer service if you believe you received this message in error."


you can use Bitquery solana APIs. You can create a free developer account and use it. Here's the link for the saved query to get SOL/USDT price. But currently Bitquery is only providing realtime data. They are adding historical data to their database too. So keep an eye out on their telegram channel and Official Twitter account to receive the updates.
Full disclosure: I work at Bitquery. Feel free to ask questions in our support channels.
